# Generate report

Tags: sql-server, sum, between

I have a table 'TableA':

TableA_ID (int)
Date (smalldatetime)
Name (string)

and a table 'TableB' linked with TableA by TableA_ID:
TableB_ID (int)
TableA_ID (int)
Description (string)
Total (double)

I want to sum up the TableB 'Total' column between two dates (TableA 'Date').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(b.total)
FROM tableB AS b
INNER JOIN tableA AS a ON a.tableA_ID = b.tableA_ID
WHERE a.date BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date>
```

Regards,
Alin

Comment: Give or take trivia in the formatting, the same as mine...maybe one of us is about correct! :D

Comment: I think @Alin Purcaru and @Jonathan Leffler have great answers  :)

Comment: presentation is everything ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT SUM(B.Total)
  FROM TableB AS B JOIN TableA AS A ON B.TableA_ID = A.TableA_ID
 WHERE A.Date BETWEEN '<early-date>' AND '<later-date>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
SELECT SUM(Total)
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.TableA_ID = TableB.TableA_ID
WHERE TableA.Date BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date'
```